# Find latest file that matches pattern in folder

Tags: java, filter, filelist

I'm writing a method that will take 2 inputs:

1. `String name`
2. `String path`

Then output the latest pdf(with pdf as extension) filename that start with name (which is a variable) and is in the path.

I am using:

```
public String getLatestMatchedFilename(String path, String name){
    File dir=new File(path);    
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.startsWith();
        }
    });
}
```

However, I don't know how to pass the the value in name into the accept method, since it's a variable and changes everytime.

Comment: That did the trick. Now I can pass the value to the accept method. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change name to one of the variables called `name`. Mark the `String name` parameter (or whatever name it will have) in your method with `final` in order to be used inside an anonymous class and use it directly.

Here is how the code should look:

```
public String getLatestMatchedFilename(String path, final String name) {
    File dir = new File(path);    
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String nameFilter) {
            return nameFilter.startsWith(name);
        }
    });
    // rest of your code ...
}
```